# Android studio does not recognize physical devices on macbook pro without usb ports

Tags: android, usb

I am trying to connect a smarthpone (samsung j7 with android 8) to android studio on a macbook pro (this device does not have usb ports, so you have to use an adapter), it does not recognize the physical device. On an imac with usb ports, the same device is recognized immediately. I'm using AndroidStudio chipmunk version (latest) on both computers.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the adapter, or adb installation

Comment: I have tested the adapter with other devices and it works fine, could you give me more information about the adb installation? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work with emulators?